# Are Displacement maps used to create normal maps?

Tags: modeling, displacement

I know displacement maps actually change geometry.  However, I find them quite useless for my mesh because in order for it to work, you need a high poly count.  I apply displacement maps before I run create normal map.

Am I using them wrong?  What's the point if it only works on your high poly?  If you're talking about VERY basic stuff like floor tiles, I guess they're useful...  On more complex models like landscaping, it it pointless?  You can't export the high poly anyway without creating a normal map.

Comment: You would use a displacement map to make a (topologically representative) mesh from an image texture. You are correct, this mesh would be high-poly, as displacement requires subdivision. However, if you have applied the displacement, you can bake the Normal details from the high poly mesh to a similar, low poly mesh (thus saving geometry). No "height" information will be altered in the low poly mesh, but its surfaces will reflect light  in a fashion consistent with the _surface angles_ that are present in the high poly mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point to true displacement is that some people use higher poly counts than you do.  All the way to adaptive subdivision, which might make a vertex for every screen pixel.

Even at low poly counts, they're useful for low-resolution displacement.  You don't need ten million vertices to turn a height map into low-poly terrain.

That doesn't mean they're useful to *you*.  Blender has all sorts of tools that are only useful to some people.  In years, I've never bothered to learn how to do camera tracking, for example.

Yes, you *can* use a displacement map to make a normal map.  Simply use your displacement as the input to a displacement node in your material, then bake your normals.  This is not the only way to make a normal map, nor is it the only thing one can do with a displacement map.

Displacement maps are useful as bump maps *without* baking as well, because they deform fine without relying on UV tangents, which allows you to use them on deforming meshes with arbitrary meshes and UV maps-- even without any UV maps at all.